# Get band values when using seaborn lineplot with ci parameter

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I want to get the bounding values when I use seaborn lineplot with the parameter `ci` set to `sd` e.g.

```
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fmri = sns.load_dataset("fmri")
ax = sns.lineplot(x="timepoint", y="signal", ci="sd", data=fmri)
```

It returns the axes object with the plot draw onto it, but how do I get the numeric values of the estimator and the bands corresponding to `sd`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sns.lineplot()` is plotting the mean of `fmri.signal` at each value of `fmri.timepoint` and adding confidence intervals by standard deviation. You can get the mean and standard deviation with native Pandas:

```
fmri.groupby('timepoint')['signal'].mean()
fmri.groupby('timepoint')['signal'].std()
```